# Where do I buy a large amount of dried vegetables?

Tags: shopping, camping

I'd like to buy a large amount of dried vegetable matter to stock up on backpacking supplies.  I'm interested in almost any kind of edible vegetables, including the generic, assorted, mixed, ground-up, and processed kind.  I'd just like to have a lot of options to look at, but CHEAP above all! Wholesale retailers are also of interest to this OP.

And why vegetables? For flavor, fiber, and vitamins.

Comment: Food dehydrators aren't terribly expensive...

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a food co-op or health food store near you? Lots of them sell in bulk, including dried veggies or dried mixes (for example refried beans or falafel). Additionally, you can ask if they offer a case discount, which means you buy a 20-or-so pound bag and sometimes can get about 10% off the bulk rate. To see if you have a co-op in your area check [coopdirectory.org](http://www.coopdirectory.org/)

Comment: I removed the statement "which are also healthy" because we tend to stay away from making any health claims on Season Advice.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the hikers that I know buy when stuff's on sale, and dehyrate their own.  (but I think they do more fruits than vegetables, for the energy needed for hiking)

As for where you buy 'large' amounts, it really depends on what sort of quantities we're talking about.  I'd really suggest trying lemontwist's advice, and looking for a local food co-op first.

If you don't have one nearby, you might try some of the 'disaster preparedness supply' websites.  Most sell full meals, but if you dig through the websites (or mail order catalogs, in case you're concerned with the government knowing that you're making these preparations), you'll find that some have bulk dried foods in either resealable cans or bagged, and each site will stock different varieties and sizes (anywhere from 1.5 oz to 2+ lbs) ... and remember, that this has no water in it, so 2lbs could be 20-40 cups); many mention '#10' can, which is roughly 13.7 cups (~3.2L)

Another option is to look for various dried 'soup mix' (also available from the emergency preparedness folks, and in some grocery stores), but check to see how much salt's been added.  A health food store's going to be more likely to have a low-salt option than your general grocery store.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great little shop just off the main bazaar in the town of Leh (in the Himalayas) that sells almost any kind of fruit or vegetable that is completely dry. I found them quite tasteful and useful for treks as you don't have to worry about your food going bad.

Actually, when I think about it, you can find dried foods in most of that town since it's a trekking center.